# How to automatically center the DIV all objects on all sides with table-cell?

Tags: css, html, center, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I would need advice on how to do that I have reached the correct result. Here is a [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/H334r/3/).

I used the main attribute `table-cell` that I reached the vertical centering, but not me centered `DIV #box` under `DIV #wrap`. Neither `ANCHOR` vercital centering under `DIV #box`. `ANCHOR` object must align automatically without specifying the size. **Images** under `ANCHOR` may have different sizes.

All `ANCHOR` objects under `DIV #box` must align automatically without any separation into `DIV` blocks. Into `DIV #box` are automatically displayed those items that can fit in there. Sorting may not be conditional size and **neither the number of items**. The only condition is the height and width of the `DIV #box`.

Example:

[image]
[image]

**Main structure**

- Sequence `ANCHOR` must not be fixed specified or limited to the number; automatically centered on all sides under `DIV #box`; automatically adjust the image size.
- `DIV #box` must be aligned horizontally to center under `DIV #wrap`, has specified a
  fixed width and height; the entire contents of the `DIV #box` must be aligned to the center, both horizontally and vertically; everything that does not fit in the block will be automatically hidden.

[image]

It may also be a solution via jQuery.

Thanks for resp.

Comment: This is really hard. I suspect it may be impossible with just CSS3 and would require a good deal of javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't allow separation in additional DIV wrappers, then it is **impossible** to achieve your result cleanly and with reusable non-hard-coded code.

You restrict development options (probably not your fault) by not allowing to change HTML structure.
But if there were no restrictions, then there would be multiple ways to solve this problem:

1. Using HTML and wrapping little objects into group wraps and a bit of CSS
2. Hard code CSS with negative margins, relative positioning for every single element
3. Achieve the same thing with jQuery / JavaScript but with lots of exceptions and computations

Because elements in HTML can be of 2 types - **block** and **inline** .
*[ let's not go here into specifics of what inline-block elements and other types are]*

If an element is of **block** type then the next proceeding element will jump to the *next row* , but if the element is of type **inline** then the next element will line up next to it if there is space in the row. The *height* of the row is dictated by the *highest element* AND NOT by *a group of highest elements* .

[image]

The only way to achieve that would be to wrap them into a group.

[image]

So in CODE this would look like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <a href="#"><img src="" /><p>TEXT</p></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="" /><p>TEXT</p></a>

    <span id="group">
        <a href="#"><img src="" /><p>TEXT</p></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="" /><p>TEXT</p></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="" /><p>TEXT</p></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#group {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#group > :first-child {
   display:block;
}
```

**[RESULT in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/H334r/8/)**